# How to set a Button borderless which is created dynamically in android?

Tags: android, button, borderless

I know how to set a button borderless in xml.But how to set button borderless in source code, because it is created dynamically.

Comment: set the shape drawable programmetically..

Answer (score 1):

Make button image and do:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_image);
```

Comment: I think, the question is about removing the default background of the button. use 
button.setBackground(android.R.color.transparent);

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

don't forget to put exactly:

**android.R.color.transparent**

if you put **R.color.transparent** only (without android), there will be an error in the code when doing this